# android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar element is not declared

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

Hi I'm new to android dev and start using Xamarin last week, I'm trying to build an app to test and learn how to use material design using `Android Support Library v7 AppCompat`.
I encounter a problem saying that the element is not declared even though I already added the component. I'm using `Xamarin Visual studio`.

[First problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPwxw.jpg)

[Then I separate the toolbar but this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDiBz.jpg)

Kindly enlighten me about whats causing this.

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you found a solution?